# why JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS is not fired?

Tags: c#, winapi

i create a job by c#

```
    public WindowsJob()
    {
        m_handle = Kernel32Dll.CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, null);
        SetJobInformation();
        SetJobCompletionPort();
    }

    private void SetJobInformation()
    {
        var info = new Win32Define.JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE,

        };

        var extendedInfo = new Win32Define.JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            BasicLimitInformation = info
        };

        int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32Define.JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
        IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

        if (!Kernel32Dll.SetInformationJobObject(m_handle
            , Win32Define.JobObjectInfoType.JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation
            , extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to set information.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }
```

i can catch JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS, JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS, JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO, but i can't catch JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS
(i write a c# program which throw new System.Exception("not handled") to kill itself, and it be caught by JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS rather than JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS).

and i tried native program, it also cant be caught by JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS.

why? is there i made any mistake?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: maybe c++ knows more about platform sdk

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the documentation for [JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which looks to be the structure by which process exit notifications are sent, we see that only a limited set of exit codes are considered an abnormal exit.

For example, to get a process to exit with STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, try the following C++ program and see whether you get the abnormal exit notification.

```
void main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    *p = 42;
}
```

In my tests, a .NET application that exits with an unhandled exception has exit code 255, which is not one of those listed as considered an abnormal exit.